# Update listBox on Main page from button click event on child window.

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox, refresh, childwindow

I have a Main page that contains a listBox.

When a user selects a profile form the list box, this opens up a child window called `pWindow`.
This window as the option to delete the current profile via a hyperlink button that opens up a another confirmation window called `dprofile`.

My question being is it possible that once a user has confirmed to delete the current profile they are in, and confirmed it in the button click on `dProfile`, how can I update the listBox in the first Main page so that the list no longer contains the deleted profile (which it is not doing at present.

In the `dProfile` window I have created an event -

```
public event EventHandler SubmitClicked;
```

Where in the OK button click I have-

```
private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (SubmitClicked != null)
  {
      SubmitClicked(this, new EventArgs());
  }
}
```

So on the Main page I have added-

```
private void deleteProfile_SubmitClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebService.Service1SoapClient client = new WebService.Service1SoapClient();

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        client.profileListCompleted += new EventHandler<profileListCompletedEventArgs>(client_profileListCompleted);
        client.profileListAsync(ID);
    }
```

I thought this may have updated the listBox as it was confirmed in the `dProfile` form however when the form closes, the listBox stays the same and I have to manually refresh the webpage to see the update. How can I do this?

Comment: after calling clear try listBox1.DataBind(); or listBox1.Refresh();

Comment: unfortunately neither seem viable, I think that would work for winForms though. Baring in mind I am not using the 'deleteProfile.SubmitClicked += new EventHandler(deleteProfile _SubmitClicked);' line that worked in your other method?

Comment: ohhhh , I believe you are not even going into that event then, you need to register the event with that line

Comment: on the Main page, after initialization you should register the event that way, it should work

Comment: problem being I am not needing to create a new 'deleteProfile' instance, whereas I was before. Is this possible< as Im not sure where this line would fit in the Main page...

Comment: are you calling deleteProfile.ShowDialog from the same page ? where you have the event?

Comment: No, if you suggest some code changes I could try and implement them.

Comment: Check  my answer, its based on my understanding and I haven't tested it

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can use static event, I don't know why I didn't suggest that earlier. Give it a shot and let me know if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it correctly then you have three pages. Main, pWindow and dProfile. [Earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535987/close-previous-window-from-current-window) you were trying to close pWindwow from dProfile and that was working properly. Now you want to refresh the listBox1 on Main Page. 
To achieve that you may follow a similar strategy. You are probably opening pWindow from Main page with something on the following line

```
pWindow pWin = new pWindow();
pWin.Show();
```

Now you may define a new event in pWindow class.

```
public event EventHandler pWindowRefeshListBox;
```

Then in your event handler for deleteProfile_SubmitClicked you may raise the event to refresh listbox1, something on the following line:

```
private void deleteProfile_SubmitClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(pWindowRefreshListBox != null)
        pWindowRefreshListBox(this, new EventArgs());
    this.Close();
}
```

Then in your main page register the event against pWin object, which you defined earlier.

```
pWin.pWindowRefreshListBox += new new EventHandler(pWindow_pWindowRefreshListBox);
```

Then define the event in Main page.

```
private void pWindow_pWindowRefreshListBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
}
```

This should refresh the listbox. I haven't test the code or the syntax. So you may check it 
before implementing.

**EDIT**
you may define the event in dProfile as static

```
public static event EventHandler SubmitClicked;
```

Then you will be able to register it in Main and pWindow against Class Name

```
dProfile.SubmitClicked += new ..............
```

Then implement it accordingly, in pWindow, close the window and in main refresh listbox

**EDIT:**

 You may create instance of deleteProfile on the main page register the following in your main

```
deleteProfile.SubmitClicked += new EventHandler(deleteProfile _SubmitClicked)
```

this should work

Comment: I tried this code and it worked once, but then it doesnt work after that, do I need to put a clear function in? I tried your original answer as I did not fully understand the edit.